# SELECT random datasets from AdventureWorks Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to select 2 random datasets of 3 cities **each** from the AdventureWorks2019 table **FROM [Person].[Address]** and insert this 2*3 random Dataset into one table.

I tried this:

```
DECLARE @City TABLE 
(
ID int IDENTITY ,
City nvarchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @City (CITY)
VALUES ('Snohomish'), ('Duvall'), ('Seattle')   -- Cities do select random datasets
    
DECLARE @ID int = (SELECT count(*) from @City)

--SELECT * FROM @City

CREATE TABLE [Person].randomtest (City nvarchar(50))

WHILE (@ID <> 0 )

BEGIN
INSERT into [Person].randomtest (City)
        
SELECT TOP 2 [City]
FROM [Person].[Address]
WHERE 1 = 1 
  AND CITY = @City.City 
  AND @City.ID = @ID
ORDER BY NEWID()
        
SET @ID = (@ID - 1)
END
```

But it does not work. They write "must declare @city". But I already declared it.

Comment: You need `;` at the ends of your statements

Comment: In your `SELECT TOP 2...` you appear to be trying to `JOIN` to the @City table variable, but you haven't actually specified that you're `JOIN`ing to that table. Also, please don't use the `WHERE` clause to set your `JOIN` conditions, those should be in `ON` statements attached to the `JOIN` itself

Comment: I used the ROW_NUMBER OVER(Partition by City order by City) for this

Answer (score 0):

> They write "must declare @city". But I already declared it.

The variable `@City` is declared, but inside the INSERT query you are using it without declaring the table to be selected.

The issue is that you are using the variable `@city`, which is type table, not well. If you want to use a column from a table, then you need to SELECT/JOIN the table in the FROM.

The following query `SELECT @City.ID` without FROM '@City.ID' make no sense, since you use `@City.ID` but you do not have this table in the query. This is exactly the mistake you are doing here.

Same when you use simple tables and not only variables. Let's say that you have tables A and B then you cannot execute query like `select a1 from A where B.b1 = 1`, since B is not SELECTED and therefore you cannot use it's columns. Check this example:

```
create table A (a1 INT)
CREATE TABLE B(b1 INT)
GO

select a1 
from A -- here you declare that you select from table A. Therefore you can use the column from A
where B.b1 = 1 -- but you cannot use column from table B if you do not declared it in the query
GO -- ERROR

select a1 
from A 
CROSS JOIN B -- This is one option to declare table B in the query
where B.b1 = 1
GO -- Run OK
```

Note! Do not use the above query. I only write it for the sake of the discussion. You have a bigger issues in your case.

(1) In order to use multiple tables in the query you need to learn about JOIN operator. JOIN is basic operation in tabular databases and it based on the relations between the tables. There are multiple type of JOIN and you need to use the one that fit your specific case.

It is clear that you did not learn SQL language, which is sad, since it can be learned in 3 full days, and you will not have such questions.

The main reasons it take longer time, are that (1) most people do not learn it in an orderly way, but jump from one question to the other. (2) It is not a related to how smart you are but most people cannot learn by themselves and they need someone to guide them - to prevent them from jumping between topics for example. This is why we have teachers.

I HIGHLY recommend to learn the full language in ordered course. If you can learn by yourself then there are multiple free online courses (like the one I will link below). If you see that this not fit you then try a book. If this not work as well then go pay for a course - paying have another advantage (if you pay then you will not want to waste the money and you will do everything you are told)

[In the following link you can find the lesson about JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). You can be lazy and learn only this part (how to use multiple tables using JOIN) or (as I suggested) leave everything aside -> take three days vacation (or a bit more if you need) -> [learn SQL language from start to end](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_intro.asp) including all the exercises.

In addition you have multiple issues with your "query". This is the only the start...

### To summarize

The main issue is not with declaring the variable in the transaction but the issue is with your SELECT query and the fact that the variable table in the SELECT query is not declared.

Check this code for example:

```
DECLARE @City TABLE (
    ID int IDENTITY ,
    City nvarchar(50)
)
INSERT INTO @City (CITY)
VALUES ('Snohomish'), ('Duvall'), ('Seattle')
-- SELECT * FROM @City

DECLARE @ID int = (SELECT count(*) from @City)

WHILE (@ID <> 0 ) BEGIN
    INSERT into [Person].randomtest (City)
        SELECT TOP 2 a.[City]
        FROM [Person].[Address] a
        INNER JOIN @City c 
            ON a.City = c.City
        WHERE 1 = 1 
            -- AND CITY = @City.City -- This used in the JOIN condition
            AND c.ID = @ID -- not sure what you meant to get here and not sure why you use WHILE loop. NOT CLEAR WHY YOU INSERT THE SAME CITY MULTIPLE TIMES (up to two times insert the same city in each loop)
        ORDER BY NEWID()
    SET @ID = (@ID - 1)
END

select * from [Person].randomtest
GO
```

**I hope that this was useful** `:-)` and that you read everything that I wrote from start to end before jumping to a solution which might not fit your real needs